# What kind of draft excluder/stopper is best for drafts?

Tags: doors, draft

The person who lives in the apartment across from me has taken up chain smoking. (Likely a new tenant rather than a new habit. Still.) The second-hand smoke is getting into my condo via the hallway door, which isn't well sealed, so I'm looking into dealing with that. There's a decently sized gap at the bottom of the door, therefore I want to start by installing a draft excluder.

I know I need a single-sided option because the metal plate on the floor of the threshold has a raised lip on the hallway side (and I'm not supposed to have visible *anything* on the hallway side.) I also don't think the "brush" variants are going to be particularly helpful since my primary goal is to keep out the drafts and cigarette smoke.

So far I've identified the following options:

- Door snake (weighted or otherwise). Not sure why these exist except maybe as an option for people who can't make modifications to their rented apartments.
- Brush seals. Seem to be good against dust/dirt but not drafts.
- Foam tape underneath the door.
- Rubber strips (eg a skirt) on the inside of the door.

I think foam tape or rubber are the likely best bet to keep out the drafts, I'm unclear about the differences between them and why I'd choose one vs the other. What kind of draft excluder/stopper is best for my use case, if my primary concern is outside air getting in?

Comment: Consider increasing the pressure in you apartment - air is coming in from the hall as the hall has a higher pressure. Otherwise that smell will still come in.

Comment: How does one increase air pressure in an apartment? My apartment is naturally drafty (12 foot windows, single paned, still trying to find anyone who will double-pane them for me), and the HVAC can only do so much ... I don't mind the air from the street getting in, it's the air from the hallway I want to exclude.

Comment: Re: increasing pressure. One option is to install a fan in your window that blows air into your apartment. The main idea is that your apartment should be pushing air out of its crevasses instead of sucking air in.

Comment: It's a historic building; a fan would be visible from the outside and is a no-go since it would change the look.

Comment: If you can get away with putting a few (4) small screws into the bottom portion of the door then check out vinyl door sweeps like this one. https://www.homedepot.com/p/M-D-Building-Products-2-in-x-36-in-Premium-Aluminum-and-Vinyl-Door-Sweep-in-Aluminum-05389/100353470 but I highly suspect this will be a game of whack-a-mole.

Comment: If it's a historic building then I am a bit surprised that the person is allowed to smoke in the apartment.

Comment: take a picture of the door threshold.  Could you mount the rubber or foam tape on the door face surface of the lip?  If you did mount it there will the exterior door surface reach this lip?  What is your door made of, wood, maybe you could cut a piece of wood and extend the door downwards ( paint grade is easy to make this invisible ).

Comment: Door is made of metal; not sure what kind but it's painted and magnets stick to it.